# Reading JSON file in Python and detecting specific keywords in field

Tags: python, json, parsing

I just started this week to learn Python and I have the following question. I have a JSON file (Aberdeen2015.json) that contains 60 lines (each line containing a newspaper article). Moreover, each line contains a list with the `date`, `title` and `body` of the article (see picture below, title cannot be seen since it's towards the end of the line).

[image]

I want to do the following: if certain keywords are in the `body` of an article, print a list with the `date` of those articles. So far I have tried to do the following:

```
with open("Aberdeen2015.json") as f:
    for i in line():
        if (' tax ' in body[i]
        or ' Tax ' in body[i]
        or ' policy ' in body[i]
        or ' Policy ' in body[i]
        or ' regulation ' in body[i]
        or ' Regulation ' in body[i]
        or ' spending ' in body[i]
        or ' Spending ' in body[i]
        or ' budget ' in body[i]
        or ' Budget ' in body[i]
        or ' central bank ' in body[i]
        or ' Central Bank ' in body[i]
        or ' Central bank ' in body[i]):

        print("date")
```

I am aware that the code might have many failures, any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Could you please post a small extract of the actual text of your JSON file? It's really hard to copy & paste text from an image. :) You should be using Python's `json` module to parse that file. FWIW, there's a compact and efficient way to solve your problem, but I'd prefer to illustrate my solution with some real data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
# import json module for parsing
import json

# define a list of keywords
keywords = ('tax', 'policy', 'regulation', 'spending', 'budget', 'central bank')

with open('test.json') as json_file:

    # read json file line by line
    for line in json_file.readlines():

        # create python dict from json object
        json_dict = json.loads(line)

        # check if "body" (lowercased) contains any of the keywords
        if any(keyword in json_dict["body"].lower() for keyword in keywords):
            print(json_dict["date"])
```

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way to do this is using set intersection.

We use the standard Python [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to parse the data, which gives us a `list` of `dict`s, one `dict` per row. Then we get the `body` field of each row, convert it to lower case and split it into single words. Then we see if that set of words has a non-empty intersection with the set of keywords. If it does, we print the date of that row.

```
import json

keywords = ('tax', 'policy', 'regulation', 'spending', 'budget', 'central bank')
keywords = set(keywords)

fname = "Aberdeen2015.json"
with open(fname) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for row in data:
    s = row['body']
    if keywords.intersection(s.lower().split()):
        print(row['date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that your json file looks like this:

```
[
    {"date": "DEC 27, 2015", "body":"the policy has been defined"},
    {"date": "AUG 15 2015", "body":"the tax and policy are done"},
    {"date": "JAN 23 2002", "body": "nothing to get from this one"}
]
```

This code works, tell me if you do not understand

```
import json, re

words = ["policy", "tax"]

def lookingfor(words):
    with open("file.json", "rb") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for line in data:
            for word in words:
                match = re.findall(word, line['body'])
                if match:
                    print(  "word matched: %s ==> date: %s" % (word, line['date']))


lookingfor(words)
```